# EntityManager "randomly" throws Exception when executing native query

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, repository, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a Spring Boot project which mostly uses Repository's for all db operations, however I have a table that is not backed by an entity and thus doesn't use a Repository. Instead I use an EntityManager and run a native query.

This works well most of the time, but every so often (but often enough that it's noticeable), the query just fails for seemingly no reason.

Here's my code:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AddChangeRequest {
  @Qualifier("a-entity-manager")
  private final EntityManager entityManager;

  public void of(G g, P p) {
    entityManager.joinTransaction();
    entityManager.createNativeQuery(
      "INSERT INTO CHANGE_REQUESTS (P_ID, G_PK) VALUES (?,?) ON CONFLICT (P_ID) DO UPDATE SET LAST_CHANGE_DATE = NOW()")
      .setParameter(1, p.getPId())
      .setParameter(2, g.getGPk())
      .executeUpdate();
  }
```

One thing to note here is that I have two EntityManagers in my project.

One `a-entity-manager` which is defined as so:

```java
@Bean
  @Qualifier("a-entity-manager")
  public EntityManager entityManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
  }
```

And another which is brought in from another project in my pom file and by scanning for the package it's in:
`@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages=....`

The error that I sometimes get typically looks something like (usually there's a few different errors back to back):

`o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : This statement has been closed.`

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doExecuteUpdate(NativeQueryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1605)
```

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: This statement has been closed.
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.checkClosed(PgStatement.java:694)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:447)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:365)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:143)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:120)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1491)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doExecuteUpdate(NativeQueryImpl.java:295)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.executeUpdate(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1605)
```

The last thing to note is that when this code is run it's as a result of a network call and there's usually a fair number of requests made in quick succession. Probably on average 10-50 calls.

Anyone have any ideas what could be going on here? I believe it may have something to do with having multiple EntityManagers because that is rather new and I don't think this happened before. Before this rather recent change this code was just using the "default" EntityManager, I didn't define my own at all.

Thanks!